# jQuery .when().done() not working

Tags: jquery, deferred

I'd like to start by saying I'm new to jQuery and I suspect I'm just doing something stupid, so hopefully this will be very simple for someone.

I'm trying to add a sliding mobile sub-menu to my website. I want an accordian effect whereby if I click one parent link, it's child sub-menu opens and all other sub-menus close. The problem is timing - the child sub-menu opens and then is closed again by the resetting of all sub-menus. I presume the answer is to use deferreds but everything I've tried has failed. This is the (currently not working) code:

```
function ResetMenu(){
    jQuery(".mobile-menu").find(".sub-menu").slideUp(100);
    jQuery(".mobile-menu").find(".menu-item-has-child").removeClass("open");
};

function OpenSubmenu(){
    jQuery(this).next("ul").slideDown(100);
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("open");
};

jQuery("li.menu-item-has-children > a").click(function(){

    if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass("open")){
        jQuery(".mobile-menu").find(".sub-menu").slideUp(100);
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("open");
    } else {
        jQuery.when(ResetMenu()).done(OpenSubmenu());
    }
    return false;
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Ronel

Comment: `ResetMenu` need to return a promise for this to work..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a common mistake in how to use `jQuery.when()`.

`jQuery.when()` requires promises as arguments.  It does not have magical powers to know when functions you pass it are somehow done.  Those functions MUST return promises that are resolved or rejected when the underlying code is done and you can then pass those promises to `jQuery.when()`.

Your `ResetMenu()` function doesn't return anything so therefore, your `jQuery.when()` doesn't wait for anything.  It executes the `.then()` handler immediately (which looks like that is not what you want).

So, in this line:

```
jQuery.when(ResetMenu()).done(OpenSubmenu());
```

`ResetMenu()` MUST return a promise for `jQuery.when()` to know when it is done.

You could fix `ResetMenu()` to work that way by doing this:

```
function ResetMenu(){
    return jQuery(".mobile-menu").find(".sub-menu").slideUp(100).promise().then(function() {
        // remove this class when the animation has completed
        jQuery(".mobile-menu").find(".menu-item-has-child").removeClass("open");
    });
};
```

And, then further, you need to change how you pass a function to `.done()` to this which both makes it just a function reference that can be executed LATER and binds a appropriate `this` value to it:

```
jQuery.when(ResetMenu()).done(OpenSubmenu.bind(this));
```

Note, the `.bind(this)` assumes that `this` is the appropriate value.  You can pass whatever value is the correct value there and that will become the `this` value inside of `OpenSubmenu()` when it is executed.

Comment: good one with the `then` callback... `.done(OpenSubmenu());` should be `.done(OpenSubmenu);`

Comment: Thank you very much, that resolves the .when part. Unfortunately the .done part is still not working - I realised that the function OpenSubmenu needs a parameter, specifically jQuery(this) needs to be passed out of the click event function. However when I tried using .done(function() {OpenSubmenu(jQuery(this));}); it all fails again. I suspect this is because I am passing a function instead of a function reference, as per your last comment, however I don't see how else this could be done. Please could you add this to your answer?

Comment: @Ronelz - Then, you can use `.bind()` like this: `jQuery.when(ResetMenu()).done(OpenSubmenu.bind(this));`  This creates a new function reference that will call `OpenSubmenu` with `this` set.  This assumes that the current value of `this` is what you want `this` to be set to inside of `OpenSubMenu()`.  You don't show enough of your code for us to know if that is the right value or not.  But, you can pass whatever the correct value is to `OpenSubMenu.bind(xxx)` and that will become the `this` value inside of `OpenSubMenu` when it is executed in that context.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a non promise object to `$.when()` the callbacks passed to `done()` is invoked immediately, in your case when `ResetMenu` is not returning anything the `OpenSubmenu` is called immediately, there is another problem also - you should not invoke `OpenSubmenu` directly(by adding `()`), you need to pass a function reference to `done()`

```
function ResetMenu() {
    jQuery(".mobile-menu").find(".menu-item-has-child").removeClass("open");
    return jQuery(".mobile-menu").find(".sub-menu").slideUp(100).promise();

};

function OpenSubmenu() {
    jQuery(this).next("ul").slideDown(100);
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("open");
};

jQuery("li.menu-item-has-children > a").click(function () {

    if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass("open")) {
        jQuery(".mobile-menu").find(".sub-menu").slideUp(100);
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("open");
    } else {
        jQuery.when(ResetMenu()).done(OpenSubmenu);
    }
    return false;
});
```