# Using Deferred with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a series of js functions that are making database calls using ajax, and I need them to finish and update variables before moving to the final function. I'm trying to use jquery $.when and am having no luck...in the attached jsfiddle you can see that the final function result is being displayed before the two primary functions are being updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/b20hvyyp/

```
var x1 = '%';
var x2 = '%';

main();

function main(){
    logProgress('start');
    $.when(a(), b()).done(logProgress(x1 + x2));
}

// called by main()
function a() {
    return $.ajax("/echo/html").pipe(function(data){
            function changex1 () {
            x1 = 'x1Changed';
        };

        setTimeout(changex1(),2000);
        logProgress(x1);
    });
}

// called by a()
function b() {
        return $.ajax("/echo/html").pipe(function(data){
            function changex2 () {
            x2 = 'x2Changed';
        };

        setTimeout(changex2(),5000);
        logProgress(x2);
    });
}

function logProgress(message){
    $('#progress').append('<li>'+message+'</li>');
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: [This question may have the answer you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575501/jquery-when-done-not-working) - your functions `a` and `b` are not returning promises, which is how `jquery.when` works

Comment: @chazsolo `$.Deferred().pipe()` returns a promise, `$.ajax()` returns a deferred, and both `a`and `b` return `$.ajax().pipe()`, so yes, his functions **are** returning a promise

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo you're right, I missed the `pipe`s. Should have been more careful reading the question.

Comment: `pipe` is deprecated since ages. You should use `then`.

Comment: `.done(logProgress(x1 + x2));` cannot work. It should be `.then(function(x1, x2) { logProgress(x1 + x2); })`

Comment: What are those `setTimeout`s supposed to do? If you want to wait for them, make deferreds for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things should be noted here. The functions a() & b() returns deferred objects from the ajax call. These deferred objects will be resolved as soon as the ajax calls complete. So, there is no way for you to detect the execution of timeout callbacks. The next thing is, when() function takes a list of deferred object and returns a single deferred object which will be resolved once all the input deferred objects are resolved. So, the done function on the when() returned deferred should get a callback function instead of a statement like logProgress(x1 + x2). Here is the link with modifications that works: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/t6nq82n1/1/)

```js
var x1 = '%';
var x2 = '%';

main();

function main(){
    logProgress('start');
    console.log('asdf')
    $.when(a(), b()).done(function() {
    logProgress(x1 + x2)
    });
//  a().done(function(){
//    logProgress(x1 + x2);
//  });
}

// called by main()
function a() {
 logProgress('a called');
  return $.ajax("/echo/html").pipe(function(data){
    function changex1 () {
    x1 = 'x1Changed';
    };
    
    changex1();
    logProgress(x1);
  });
}

// called by a()
function b() {
 logProgress('b called')
  return $.ajax("/echo/html").pipe(function(data){
    function changex2 () {
    x2 = 'x2Changed';
    };
    
    changex2();
    logProgress(x2);
  });
}

function logProgress(message){
    $('#progress').append('<li>'+message+'</li>');
}
```

```html
<ul id="progress">
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

according to Deffered documentation your code should be like this:

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

main();

function main(){
    logProgress('start');
    $.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( x1, x2 ) {
      logProgress(x1 + x2)
    });
    a();
    b();
}

// called by main()
function a() {
  return $.ajax("/echo/html").then(function(data){
        x1 = 'x1Changed';
        logProgress(x1);
      d1.resolve(x1);
  });
}

// called by a()
function b() {
  return $.ajax("/echo/html").then(function(data){
        x2 = 'x2Changed';
        logProgress(x2);
      d2.resolve(x2);
  });
}

function logProgress(message){
    $('#progress').append('<li>'+message+'</li>');
}
```

when expects Defereds,  defereds should be resolved of rejected,  i'm not sure why you used timeouts as they really caused delay of execution setting of x1 and x2 to after main function

Comment: This isn't the actual code in my program, I just slapped it together to create an example of the problem I was having, and used the Timeout function just to insure that some time passed before the function completed.